# #nav interfering with cycle

Tags: jquery, cycle

I am using the following jQuery .cycle plug in within the Twitter Bootsrap structure, which also uses nav as a div class. How can I get this to run without using #nav as the name of the div?

Thanks internet peoples.

Joey

```
<style type="text/css">
#slideshow { left: 20px }
#nav { width: 100%; height: 80px; margin: 15px;  }
#nav li { width: 50px; float: left; margin: 8px; list-style: none }
#nav a { width: 50px; padding: 3px; display: block; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li.activeSlide a { background: #88f }
#nav a:focus { outline: none; }
#nav img { border: none; display: block }
</style>
```

```
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/chili-1.7.pack.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#slideshow').before('<ul id="nav">').cycle({
        fx:     'fade',
        speed:  'fast',
        timeout: 0,
        pager:  '#nav',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
            return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>';
        }
    });
});
</script>

<div id="slideshow" class="pics">
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach4.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach5.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach6.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach7.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach8.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you define the selector of the pager in the options, you can give it any ID you want. Just change all the instances of `nav` in the cycle css and initialization code to something else.

Comment: I redefined the pager # as #slide and made it work on the fiddle, but not within bootstrap. Thanks for the help tho.